# Where are hardware interrupt handlers stored?

Tags: cpu, x86, interrupts

I've been doing some research on interrupts and it seems that pointers to software interrupt handlers are located in the first 1024 bytes of memory. I haven't been able to find anything about the equivalent for hardware interrupts, so would anyone be willing to enlighten me?

Comment: Assuming you are interested in the IBM PC architecture, you are looking for information on the [PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_Interrupt_Controller), [APIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller), [8259](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8259) (and descendants) and [interrupt request subsystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, by the way. It definitely looks like a legitimate question to me, and curiously, the answer certainly doesn't appear to be trivial to find. I'd expect the 8259 PIC to hold addresses to direct the CPU to when a hardware interrupt line is raised, and later PC variants (including with APICs) to build on top of that, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: this is a good question and objective but people here are often terrible with theoretical questions.. and such questions often get closed(often the stated reason for closing makes no sense). This kind of theoretical question will get a better answer on arstechnica forum

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research I found that hardware interrupts use the same interrupt vector that software interrupts use.

[Source](http://retired.beyondlogic.org/interrupts/interupt.htm#2)